# GNOME shell extension working with Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, firefox-extensions, chrome-extension

Recently installed 18.04, and, as the title explains, I have managed to get `GNOME Shell integration extension` to work with Firefox (version 60.0.1) but not with Chromium (version 66.0.3359.139).

I have tried what the link on the [GNOME extensions page](https://extensions.gnome.org/) suggests:

> Refer [documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) for instructions about installing connector.

and rebooted but that has not solved the problem.

Interestingly enough, before my recent fresh install of 18.04, I was using 17.10 with GNOME and the Chromium integration was working properly.

Some hints on how to debug and fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/04/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04     there's about the extension connector and it worked for me, no any complications to get it done with chrome

Comment: Thanks.  However, assuming you are referring to section/point 9 in that list, no, that does not work.  Again, no issues with Firefox.  However, being that my main browser is chromium, I would like to get that to work.

Comment: strange indeed, about chromium I had issues with user login, etc...maybe try with chrome and if there it will work it's the chromium issue

Comment: Thanks @PawełG for the suggestion. I guess I could do that for debugging purposes.  However, I am not too keen on having to switch to Chrome (from Chromium) only to get this to work.  If I ever try this I will report results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Chromium (but not with Chrome or Firefox) after installing 18.04.1. Today I realized that it is the snap version of Chromium rather than the universe version 18.04 comes with. So I removed the snap version and installed the universe version of Chromium and the problem was solved.

Comment: I have release 18.04.1 as well and still have the issue.