# Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME shell extensions not working after installing Chromium/Chrome

Tags: chromium, snap, gnome-shell-extension

I recently did a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04 and installed chromium web browser. I followed [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) and [these](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/install-gnome-extensions-google-chrome) instructions to add the gnome shell extensions vai google web store and from terminal. When I try to add extensions I still get this message

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer [documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) for instructions about installing connector.

I have no idea what the problem could be. Should I reinstall chromium?
I'm not familiar with how snap works, but I installed chromium from the Ubuntu software store. According [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039082/gnome-shell-extension-working-with-firefox-but-not-chrome) they suggest installing the universe version of chromium. I'm not sure what the difference is here. Would someone explain this please.

Answer (score 0):

The 'universe' version of an app is a non-Snap installation using a package from the Ubuntu repositories for your version, e.g., https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/chromium-browser . Install that with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install chromium-browser` after uninstalling the Snap version.

Answer (score 0):

Snap is a way to install packages, but it is generally better to install the apt version instead in most cases.  It is what is used by the operating system officially.  Snap is a plugin for additional packages.

```
sudo snap remove chromium
```

To remove the snap

Then

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install chromium-browser -y
```

To install the normal Non-snap Chromium package

Comment: tried that and it didn't work. Actually had to remove the extenssions in chrome because it was crashing my browser.

Comment: apt install chromium-browser uses actually the snap installation.